# twitter4j logins using different accounts

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am totally confused over the twitter4j API and I think I could really use your help.

I am trying to build a desktop twitter client in java using the twitter4j API but somehow I am forced to used the OAuth method no matter what.

In the simplest of scenarios I only want my user to be able to login dynamically (like in tweekdeck) and post a tweet. However, using OAuth authentication my user will be forced to go through a number of steps to retrieve his tokens for no apparent reason.

To put it simply, I don't remember doing any of these when using tweekdeck for example. How can I go around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tweetdeck is owned by twitter now, isn't it? By default it's an accepted app.

Comment: so... there is no way to circumvent the entire procedure and make my app "act" like tweetdeck..?

Comment: No 3rd party apps have to be accepted by the twitter user.

Comment: That's very unfortunate. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Hey I am working on the same thing right now.

My solution : embed a browser and do the authentification from there.

I am using javafx which has a browser that is already ready, and I go through the whole thing like that, I don't think you will find a better solution.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question because it doesn't avoid the extra steps.

Comment: There is no other way to do it. You have to go through a we browser at least once to authenticate.